# Google Sheets Javascript indexOf error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, error-handling, indexof

I'm have a crazy time trying to get around an error when using `indexOf()` on a cell without the index criteria.. in this case a comma: indexOf(",") . BTW, I get the same issue when trying to do a .split(",") on a cell with no commas.

[image: Picture of the problem]

Is there a way around this so if there are no commas, I can give a variable a value?

Here's the code:

```
/**
@customfunction
*/
function INDEX_TEST(input){
    var a = 0;
    if (input.indexOf(",") > -1){
      a = 999;
    }
    else {
      a = 0;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a link to a google sheet

[Google Sheet with example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Zp_ux3IbU4iatnSAtYdtkePQhZ6iURNtms3LFJatOY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error when `input` is a number not a string. Numbers do not have `indexOf` or any other string methods. So you have to convert it to string:

```
if (input.toString().indexOf(",")>-1){a = 999;}
```

or

```
if ((input + '').indexOf(",")>-1){a = 999;}
```

Comment: AHAaaa!! Not it makes perfect sense. Now the split and search are working as they should too :) . Thanks for your help and not laughing at me :D